# This Computer Can't Connect to the Remote Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

Here is what I did:

I right clicked on my computer and went to properties and then enabled remote desktop.  I then added my self as a User allowed to connect to the server.  It is running win2k3 Storage.  Next I tried to login and couldn't, so I added Administrator and tried to login using that login and couldn't.  Each time it says "This computer Can't Connect to the Remote server".  Does that mean that if I find the right "That Computer" I can and it is a client problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the Startup Type of the TS service? Is it set to disabled? If so, set it to automatic, then reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

Terminal services service is running.

Firewall port *really* is open (disable the firewall if you want to make sure)

Ensure that your client and server are both running the matched version of TS and TS client

Try turning the server to 'less secure" mode in the remote tab

Comment: What do you mean by matched TS and TS client.  I connect through RDP and Remote Desktop Connection Tool Correct?

Comment: My TS service isn't running and it is greyed out so I can't start it.
I'm logged in as Admin

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=278657 It is grayed out by design.  Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a TS conection to itself (127.0.0.1) to discard network conectivity issues. Ping remote server. Try using computer name and ip adress to discard name solving issues. Check also you're using as username remotecomputername\administrator .